# How to organise your Go project in the right way?

Tags: go, go-get

I have problems setting up my first go project. I want to keep my packages out of my git repository.

`go get` installs my packages by default in my `/src` folder. This way I can't simply ignore a folder to ignore all packages.

Can I install all my packages in for example `/pkg` and how would I do this? Is there a Go way of solving this issue?

In large open source projects written in Go like for example Kubernetes I cannot find a `/src` directory.

Comment: Which version of go are you using?

Comment: I have go1.13 darwin/amd64 installed

Comment: Just read How to Write Go Code and stick to it. Dead simple.

Comment: packages are managed auto by GOPATH or Gomodule. User only care using `go get ...` to fullfill gopath or mod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like an issue in your workspace.

Your workspace directory should look like this, but your workspace should **not** be the root of your repo.

```
/bin //<--compiled binaries
/src
   /adomain.com/yourstuff //<--these folders are where your repo root should be
   /gihub.com/otherstuff //<--these folders are your dependencies
/pkg //<-- installed packages / program files
```

Read the official Go documentation here:

https://golang.org/doc/code.html

A widely-used standard for organizing projects is below:

https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout

See also: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html

Comment: Is it common practise to add the installed packages in the git repository?

Comment: No. Go get will auto-download dependencies (in theory). If you follow the steps in the first link above, everything works well.

Your dependencies should be fully-qualified, eg. "github.com/user/project"

Comment: Do you know why for example open source projects like Kubernetes do not have a src folder in their repository?

Comment: @VolatileCoder: You references appear to be obsolete. They do not appear to have been updates for Go modules.

Comment: Without modules, it _is_ common to store dependencies in the git repository, in the `/vendor` directory. Although this isn't required, or always desired.

Comment: @thiloilg the `src` directory *is not your project*. It is a workspace containing all your non-module projects and their dependencies. If you're checking out directly into `src`, you haven't read the linked guides. On the other hand, if you are using modules, any downloaded dependencies are in a cache directory, also outside your project directory. Modules also largely obviates the need for vendoring dependencies since it specifies versions and hashes; I personally have not found it at all common to see a vendor directory in a module project.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks I understand. I have a mono repo with a couple of node microservices so i can't use src as my workspace. I guess modules is the way to go then.

Comment: Sure you can, you just have to put your project in a reasonable place, again according to the linked documentation. `src/myscm.co/myproject/mypackage` can contain NodeJS code, it will just be ignored.